# Angular 9 - Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: StaticInjectorError[Http]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Http

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm new in Angular testing. Now I am trying to test **services**.
When I run `ng test` for my unit tests, and when those tests use the service,
I am getting the error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]:  
StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
```

Here is my spec file:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { ContactService } from "./contact.service";
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

describe("ContactService", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, HttpClientModule], 
        providers: [ContactService],
    });
  });
  
  it("should ...", inject([ContactService], (service: ContactService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

And this is my .sevice.ts file imports:

```
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Contact } from '../';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are injecting `http` module from `@angular/common` but you have imported `@angular/http` module.

Change to this:

```
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and you just need this:

```
imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
```

or instead of actual `ContactService` you can mock it:

```
class MockContactService {
   // properties and methods to mock
}
```

now you can use this within your provider:

```
providers: [
   {
     provide: ContactService,
     useClass: MockContactService
   }
]
```